# Configuring Prometheus Go client from `metrics:` field tags

Tags: go, apache-kafka, prometheus

I need to send [kafka-go](https://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go)'s internal statistics to Prometheus. The [`ReaderStats`](https://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go/blob/master/reader.go#L506) struct already defines field tags beginning with `metrics:...` which look like they are meant to be used to configure Prometheus.

But so far I failed to find any existing code which could take advantage of these field tags.

Is there such existing code to do that or do I have to "manually" do the usual `prometheus.NewCounterVec()...`?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/go-application/#adding-your-own-metrics

Comment: Thanks but no. I already know how to add metrics. I was just wondering if there is any existing tool which could take advantage of these field tags and help me avoid having to define the metrics individually

Comment: It is weird they added those tags and there is no documentation related to it, You can open a ticket on git to directly ask the developers this or create a custom metric and parse this struct in the function

Comment: Hi i looked trough the code seems the metrics is more of documentation tag to tell user which of the exported kafka metric is stored in which variable

Comment: Yes that's all I found so far too. It's just as a relative newcomer to this ecosystem I was wondering whether I'm missing something that more experienced users are aware of.